# Is this appender, with realloc function safe?

Tags: c

Just finished putting this function together from some man documentation, it takes a char* and appends a const char* to it, if the size of the char* is too small it reallocates it to something a little bigger and finally appends it. Its been a long time since I used c, so just checking in.

```
// append with realloc
int append(char *orig_str, const char *append_str) {
    int result = 0; // fail by default

    // is there enough space to append our data?
    int req_space = strlen(orig_str) + strlen(append_str);
    if (req_space > strlen(orig_str)) {
        // just reallocate enough + 4096
        int new_size = req_space;
        char *new_str = realloc(orig_str, req_space * sizeof(char));

        // resize success.. 
        if(new_str != NULL) {
            orig_str = new_str;
            result = 1; // success
        } else {
            // the resize failed.. 
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't reallocate memory\n");
        }
    } else {
        result = 1;
    }

    // finally, append the data
    if (result) {
        strncat(orig_str, append_str, strlen(append_str));
    }

    // return 0 if Ok
    return result;
}
```

Comment: you forgot about ending `\0`

Comment: Site policy is to not edit answers into your question -- instead, post it as an answer. (If you're looking for further review of working code, post on codereview.stackexchange.com; or if you have substantially changed the code and are still having difficulty then post a new question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not usable because you never tell the caller where the memory is that you got back from `realloc`.

You will need to either return a pointer, or pass `orig_str` by reference.

Also (as pointed out in comments) you need to do `realloc(orig_str, req_space + 1);` to allow space for the null terminator.

---

Your code has a some inefficient logic , compare with this fixed version:

```
bool append(char **p_orig_str, const char *append_str)
{
    // no action required if appending an empty string
    if ( append_str[0] == 0 )
         return true;

    size_t orig_len = strlen(*p_orig_str);
    size_t req_space = orig_len + strlen(append_str) + 1;
    char *new_str = realloc(*p_orig_str, req_space);

    // resize success.. 
    if(new_str == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't reallocate memory\n");
        return false;
    }

    *p_orig_str = new_str;
    strcpy(new_str + orig_len, append_str);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Since code has all ready computed the length of `append_str`, could use the likely faster `memcpy(new_str + orig_len, append_str, append_len + 1)` rather than `strcpy()`.

Comment: is passing an address of a pointer quicker? (and why?). Also thanks, still figuring out what you did here, but I should get it.

Comment: @MichaelICE quicker than what?  It's *necessary* otherwise the caller does not know where the reallocated space is.

Comment: My var before the call was char *s, and called like append(s.., with your changes I'd have to call it like append(&s - I don't see a difference, or am I missing something rudimentary.

Comment: @MichaelICE yes, in your original version the calling code does not know where the reallocated memory is. It would continue to try and access the old block that has been freed, since you never tell the calling code where the new block of memory is.   (If `realloc` was able to take more space without having to move the block, then it might *appear* as if your code was working, but it would go horribly wrong if the block did have to move).

Comment: But doesn't assigning the return of realloc to the passed in value do it? i.e: orig_str = new_str;

Comment: @MichaelICE That's inside the function. C uses pass-by-value; if the function is `append(s, ...` then nothing the function does can change `s`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Your function works perfectly in valgrind, where mine was losing memory. Thanks

Comment: Updated the post with new code, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

This logic doesn't make any sense:

```
// is there enough space to append our data?
int req_space = strlen(orig_str) + strlen(append_str);
if (req_space > strlen(orig_str)) {
```

As long as `append_str` has non-zero length, you're always going to have to re-allocate.

The main problem is that you're trying to track the size of your buffers with `strlen`. If your string is NUL-terminated (as it should be), your perceived buffer size is always going to be the exact length of the data in it, ignoring any extra.

If you want to work with buffers like this, you need to track the size in a separate `size_t`, or keep some sort of descriptor like this:

```
struct buffer {
    void    *buf;
    size_t   alloc_size;
    size_t   used_amt;    /* Omit if strings are NUL-terminated */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you recommend I pass in a size_t of the buffer size, or use a struct?

Comment: It really depends on the rest of your application's needs.